# new google spreadsheet script function setvalue set everything always as string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have issue from yesterday. I decided to move one of spreadsheets to New Google Spreadsheets and it just started to be problem.

In old Google Spreadsheets everything was working:

```
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
sh.getSheets()[0].getRange("A1").setValue(1);`
```

It should set value as "1", but it always set it as string "1.00000000000000"

To be sure that it is a string I used `getSheetValues` and unfortunately it confirms my theory (it shows type as "String" in script editor.
When I type number in spreadsheet by hand, function `getSheetValues` return Integer.

I've tried setValue with `setValue(parseInt(1))` or `setValue(Number(1))`.

Is this bug in Google Apps Script or is there some bug in my thinking?

Answer (score 1):

When I run this function in a new spreadsheet (new version ) I get the Log result below...

```
function test(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sh.getSheets()[0].getRange("C1").setValue(1);
  Logger.log(  typeof(sh.getSheets()[0].getRange("C1").getValue()));
}
```

[image]

**BUT** if I set the format in the cell to **'plain text'** then obviously I get a string...  Nothing abnormal I guess...

[image]

---

**EDIT** this seems to work only if spreadsheet settings are set to US, I tried other formats and get *strange results*... see comments below.

---

Comment: Hello,It seems that it is working when regional settings are US, but let's change it to other and we have:
- Polish - 1.00000000000000,
- German - 100.000.000.000

What's going on?

The wayaround of the problem is to use setFormula function like `setFormula("=1")`

Comment: You're right... this is a serious bug... 100000000000000 is a number but slightly different from 1 :-D  You should post it on the issue tracker

Comment: It is posted alreay, so I've joined to that issue
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3693&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner